# iPhone - Getting a reliable timestamp from the app to be store into external mysql database

Tags: iphone, mysql, timestamp

I want to write into a mysql database a timestamp in real milliseconds (I mean not just seconds x 1000).

How may I achieve to get that timestamp into the app. I saw that some methods on NSDate could work, but they are based onto the iPhone date/time, that can be changed by the user, so using those methods would conclude to "fake" timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any timestamp generated off the local clock will be subject to the same attack, so you'll have to find a reliable, trustworthy source of time information in its stead. An SSL-secured server would do. You'll also have to account for lag in contacting the server, which can be hundreds of milliseconds or more on an EDGE WWAN connection.

From there, you would write the data to the database the same way you would write any other data.